# Can i reverse the upgrade from websocket back to http?

Tags: http, websocket

I had a data received by websocket client Now i want it to send to http server . Is there any method to store the data outside message event ? 
Or
 Can i convert websocket client back to http client ??

Answer (score 0):

No, a WebSocket connection can't be "downgraded" back to HTTP.

But yes, moving the information out of the WebSocket event and starting a new HTTP request is quite trivial... though implementation details would (obviously) depend on language, environment etc'. i.e., a browser client implementation will be very different from a C client.

Note that the server can't initiate an HTTP request, but the server can ask the client to do so.